# mysqli query does not update in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I am building a  script to display some 24 hour charts. I am attempting to make 12 charts. One 24 hour (last hour) chart for each five minute data set i have collected. I am running accross an issue where my mysql command will not update the $hour_position. I've read many while loop inside while loop questions and have tried to construct a foreach alternative, and also tried to reset the query array, but none of this has worked. Any comments or links to another thread that can solve this problem would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
$hour_position = 00;
$htime = -1;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime($htime." day", $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);

while($hour_position < 60){
    $price_history_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dbTable` WHERE `server_time` > '$date' AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM `server_time`) like $hour_position ORDER BY `server_time` ASC");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($price_history_qry)){
        //Create a couple of arrays to build a chart. 
    }
    //Build chart here
    echo $chart;
    $hour_position = $hour_position +05;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad), as your `00` and `05` will default to `0` and `5`? ie. `$hour_position = str_pad(00,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);` / `$hour_position = str_pad($hour_position +05,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: I haven't, I will try it. I actually haven't heard of that one.

Comment: unfortunately this did not work either.

Comment: Turns out i had  a mysqli_close($con) in the //build chart here section of my code. When i removed that the loops work fine.
I discovered this by testing the loop with basic variables and slowly adding in my previous code. Unfortunately the problem wasn't listed in my submitted code, but problem is solved. Sorry for the goose chase. I will look at this kind of troubleshooting before i submit for help again.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  $hour_position  in quote like

```
      ' $hour_position '
```

or you can use

```
      ". $hour_position ."
```

Comment: Echo $hour_position and your query before executing it, see the values it gives..!!

Comment: means it didn't change value of $hour_position ?

Comment: Correct, in the query string only. Everywhere below it changes. But not in the mysql_query.

Comment: Did you try putting it as Parameter ... $hour_position as parameter..??

Comment: hmmm.. I haven't heard of that either, but i can't find anything relating to it. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a small mistake. The variable inside single quotes will not be evaluated as variable. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446245/3049065). you need to change the select query like below.

```
$price_history_qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `dbTable` WHERE `server_time` > '".$date."' AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM `server_time`) like ".$hour_position." ORDER BY `server_time` ASC");
```

And i haven't find any update query in your code. As you said you are using the update query inside while loop. So first check whether the variable has the value and then check whether it entering to while loop like below.

```
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($price_history_qry)    
    var_dump($result);    
    while($result){
           //Create a couple of arrays to build a chart. 
           var_dump("entered");
   }
```

Try to use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function to debug.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help (everyone). @mahendran, I have tried multiple variations of quotes (and just tried your suggestion again) and it doesn't change. I have used  var_dump to find out that my query variable $hour_position is not updating inside the SELECT query. I may have mispoken earlier. I am not using an UPDATE query. I am trying to update a variable in my query. I am trying to pull x data from database, process it, display it , then x + 05. Loop back through query pulling x +05 from db, process it, display it, then x +05 again...until I reach 60.